# Creating url rewrite for old url

Tags: product, product-attribute, url-rewrite, magento-1.5

As part of product data migration from one store to another i need to change url keys on some of the products. Entire process is being done in shell script.

So imagine i used to have product with following url key: `nice-prod1` . It used to be in some category and whatnot. Now, after migration, it has become: `nice-prod2`. It's accessible by it's new key so everything is fine. But the first one is not working anymore. So what I need, is to create url rewrites that redirect `nice-prod1` to `nice-prod2`.

I tried to achieve this using `setData('save_rewrites_history', true)`; before saving changes in product (which is part of collection), but no url rewrites are generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the admin feature. Go to Catalog → URL Rewrite Management. See [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/urlrewrite/index) for some more info.

To code it yourself, [here](https://gist.github.com/byjujohn/5508233) is a GIST with the code you need.

```
Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setIsSystem(0)->setOptions('RP')->setIdPath('Imported-Old-Website-URL-test1')->setTargetPath('alicia-suspender-skirt-32360')->setRequestPath('SHOPONLINE.aspx?Product=Alicia Skirt&amp;Brand=Lascivious Test&amp;PID=1975')->save();
Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setIsSystem(0)->setOptions('RP')->setIdPath('Imported-Old-Website-URL-test2')->setTargetPath('alicia-suspender-skirt-32360')->setRequestPath('SHOPONLINE.aspx?Product=Alicia Skirt&Brand=Lascivious Test&PID=1975')->save();
```

Comment: How do I get the current rewrite rule(s) for product in case i want to code it myself?

Comment: Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->getResourceCollection() will give you a collection and/or you can load single records. See app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite.php